# Get index paths of cells as user drags an item in UITableView

Tags: ios, swift

I need to implement a feature where cells show their position on the table. As the user drags a cell I need to update the numbers with the new positions. I'm using the Drag & Drop API that became available starting on iOS 11, but there doesn't seem to be a way to get the updated index paths as the user drag cells. Each cell just keep same index path as before the drag started.

Just to better explain this with an example. I have the following list:

1. Item A
2. Item B
3. Item C

Now if I go and drag Item C and put it in between Item A and B, I need the cells to update that number in real-time as the user drags it. So In real-time the numbers would then become:

1. Item A
2. Item C
3. Item B

Additionally, I need to be able to set the background color of the dragged cell. I've tried using drag preview parameters' background color, but that only sets the border color and not the entire cell's background color.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, dropSessionDidUpdate session: UIDropSession, withDestinationIndexPath destinationIndexPath: IndexPath?) -> UITableViewDropProposal {
     if session.localDragSession != nil { // Drag originated from the same app.
         if currentDestinationIndexPath != destinationIndexPath {
              //Here I need to update the rows so they display their new position 
              //in the table but all rows are still reported having same index path as before the drag started
         }
         return UITableViewDropProposal(operation: .move, intent: .insertAtDestinationIndexPath)
     }
        
     return UITableViewDropProposal(operation: .cancel, intent: .unspecified)
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, itemsForBeginning session: UIDragSession, at indexPath: IndexPath) -> [UIDragItem] {
     currentDestinationIndexPath = indexPath
     return [UIDragItem(itemProvider: NSItemProvider())]
}
```

Comment: can you please share your code ?

Comment: what `UICollectionViewDropProposal` you are using ?

Comment: I added the code. I'm using UITableView, not UICollectionView.

Comment: you are getting indexpath in `currentDestinationIndexPath`

Comment: why you need each cell changed index path ? can you guide me what you want to achieve so that i might be able to help you ... maybe there are other ways to solve this issue

Comment: I added more info. Thanks.

Comment: So if you change you datasource like this to insert values from the index it started drag to destination index ... and drop initially started index from datasource you will get what you desire to achieve ? Is not it so ?

Answer (score 0):

To implement this theres two `TableViewDelegateMethod` you have to implement.

While changing the position of the cell , you also have to update the datasource of your table view .

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, canMoveRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {
    return true
}
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, moveRowAt sourceIndexPath: IndexPath, to destinationIndexPath: IndexPath) {
//products is my datasource i.e [String]
        let productToMove = products[sourceIndexPath.row]
        products.insert(productToMove, at: destinationIndexPath.row)
        products.remove(at: sourceIndexPath.row)
    }
```

Comment: moveRowAt is not getting called while user is dragging, only at the end.